Matrix-valued contour integral
I am dealing with integrals of the form
$$ T_n = \frac{1}{2\pi \mathrm i} \oint_C \frac{z^n}{A(z)}\, \mathrm dz , $$
where $C$ is a contour in the complex plane and $A(z)$ is matrix-valued and polynomial in $z$.
A relatively simple example would be $A(z) = zX - Y$, and let us assume that $X$ is invertible and that the contour encloses all eigenvalues of $Y X^{-1}$.
Then,
$$ T_n = X^{-1} \frac{1}{2\pi \mathrm i} \oint_C \frac{z^n}{z - Y X^{-1}}\, dz = X^{-1} \bigl[ Y X^{-1} \bigr]^n $$
by holomorphic functional calculus.
Anything beyond this simple example, I do not know how to approach. In my concrete problem, $A(z)$ has an extra $z^2$ term, and the contour might not include all poles. Could someone point me at some general theory dealing with this kind of problem?
Edit to clarify what I am looking for. Given a concrete $A(z)$, I can of course determine $T_n$ element-wise. However, I am looking for theory relating somehow the operators $T_n$ and $A(z)$, like in the "simple example". For example, if $A(z) = z^2 W - z X + Y$, are there any connections I can make between $T_n$ and the $W$, $X$, $Y$?

What does it mean to divide by a matrix-valued function?

I mean the matrix inverse. (This seems to be common notation in this context, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus#Functional_calculus_for_a_bounded_operator There are no ordering issues, since the numerator is a scalar.)

My problems can be solved using the theory of holomorphic operator-valued functions or operator pencils, in particular Keldysh's theorem. I apologize if that wasn't very clear from the question - it is difficult to describe what you want, when you don't know what you want.
In this theory, a generalized eigenvalue of the operator pencil $A(z)$ is defined as a $z$ where $N[A(z)] \neq 0$, where $N$ denotes the null space. For an eigenvalue $z_k$, the right and left eigenvectors $v_k$ and $w_k$ satisfy $A(z_k)\, v_k = 0$ and $w_k^\intercal\, A(z_k) = 0$.
Keldysh's theorem allows us to express the integral $T_n$ defined above in terms of the eigenvalues inside the contour and the corresponding eigenvectors. Generally, that can become a bit complicated because $A(z)$ may have zeroes of order larger than one and in this case, the result will involve "chains of generalized eigenvectors". In the case $A(z) = z - X$ where the eigenvalues / eigenvectors agree with the ordinary definition, these chains are the Jordan chains.
In my application, it was okay to assume that all eigenvalues are semi-simple, meaning that all zeroes of $A(z)$ are of order one. (Note that there may still be multiple eigenvectors corresponding to an eigenvalue.) Keldysh's theorem is then the quite elegant statement
$$ T_n = \frac{1}{2\pi \mathrm i} \oint_\gamma \frac{z^n}{A(z)}\, \mathrm dz = \sum_k z_k^n \sum_\ell v_{k\ell}\, w_{k\ell}^\intercal . $$
Here, $k$ runs over all eigenvalues inside the contour and $\ell$ enumerates the eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalues. The eigenvectors must be normalized so that $w_{k\ell}^\intercal A'(z_k) v_{k\ell'} = \delta_{\ell\ell'}$.
Literature recommendation:

W.-J. Beyn, An integral method for solving nonlinear eigenvalue problems
F. Güttel and F. Tisseur, The nonlinear eigenvalue problem
R. Mennicken and M. Möller, Non-Self-Adjoint Boundary Eigenvalue Problems


Check out the book "Harmonic analysis of functions of several complex variables in the classical domains" by LK Hua. Incidentally I should say that LK Hua is a very interesting person!

Thank you, I appreciate the response. I have had a look into the book, and it seems very dense and its relevance not immediately obvious. It starts with defining these "classical domains" and "characteristic manifolds", which don't seem connected to my problem. I see some integrals that look somewhat similar, but the integration seems to be performed "over the set of all real symmetric matrices of order n" or so.

I'm sorry, I misread your question. I thought you were integrating over matrices. I didn't realize that you're integrating over a curve. You'll have to use complex analysis for that, the usual deal with poles.
